# Can generate a Certificate for an RSA public key

Tags: android, certificate, rsa, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to get a `Certificate` for an RSA public key to store it in a `KeyStore`. For this, I use the code below :

```
        certificates=new Certificate[1];
        myEncodedPublicKey=myKey.getPublic().getEncoded();
        byteStream=new ByteArrayInputStream(myEncodedPublicKey);
        certificates[0] = myCertificateFactory.generateCertificate(byteStream);
```

Despite a non empty encoded public key, I get the following error : `Unable to initialize, java.io.IOException: Short read of DER length`.

Does anyone know what could be the origin of this problem?

Comment: I'm afraid you are confusing a public key and certificate. An X509 certificate is *not* equivalent to a public key. It **contains** a public key, along with much other information. Furthermore, you can cannot create an X509 certificate without having the private key that will be used to sign the certificate. In short, if all you have is a public key then you can't store it in a keystore. You could create a keypair(public + private), then create a certificate containing your target public key, then sign it with your private key, then import it into a keystore as a trusted certificate.

Comment: I already have a public AND a private key. And if I want a `Certificate`, it is precisely to encapsulate my public key for storing it in my `KeyStore` with ` myKeyStore.setKeyEntry(myKeyAlias, myKeyPair.getPrivate(), myPassword, certificates)`.

Comment: Very good. Then you'll have to create your own certificate. This is most easily done offline with keytool or openssl. If you must do it from within Java then the bcpkix library is probably the easiest solution. You should be able to find many examples online, including here on SO.